# Como configurar Autoload Composer?

Tags: php, autoload

Estou me deparando muito com esse autoload em php, resolvi estudar a respeito dele, consegui entender uma boa parte, mas estou com uma unica duvida bem especifica.

Dentro do arquivo `composer.json`, no trecho:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\" : "App/"
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber em `"App\\"` a oque isto esta se referindo dentro de uma estrutura de pastas de um projeto? namespaces? a um diretorio especifico? a uma classe?

e o seu respectivo valor? "App/".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A especificação de *autoload* do PSR-4 descreve como a classe deve ser carregada dentro do seu projeto. No Composer ao definir o *json* temos essas duas partes:

```
{ "Namespace\\Base\\" : "diretorio/raiz" }
```

Assim, ao utilizar essa configuração no seu `composer.json`, você permite que o restante dos arquivos que serão carregados tenham essa espécie de "prefixo".

Exemplo: ao fazer um `use Namespace\Base\Http\BaseController` ele irá incluir o arquivo `diretorio/raiz/http/BaseController.php` no seu código.

Alguns outros exemplos podem ser vistos na [especificação do PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

```
Fully Qualified Class Name    | Namespace Prefix   | Base Directory           | Resulting File Path
----------------------------- |--------------------|--------------------------|-------------------------------------------
\Acme\Log\Writer\File_Writer  | Acme\Log\Writer    | ./acme-log-writer/lib/   | ./acme-log-writer/lib/File_Writer.php
\Aura\Web\Response\Status     | Aura\Web           | /path/to/aura-web/src/   | /path/to/aura-web/src/Response/Status.php
\Symfony\Core\Request         | Symfony\Core       | ./vendor/Symfony/Core/   | ./vendor/Symfony/Core/Request.php
\Zend\Acl                     | Zend               | /usr/includes/Zend/      | /usr/includes/Zend/Acl.php
```